# how to display an activity in tabhost FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tablelayout

[image]

Actually there are five tabs in this screen.and there is title "show Map" ,to show the map .when i click on the tab items the corresponding screens will be displayed in the FrameLayout
which is as shown in the fig.

similarly i want to display the map in the same FrameLayout with i click on the "Show Map" which is displayed as title.

this is my code.

```
 LinearLayout im=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.appactivity);
   im.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           //I need to write the code to display the map in FrameLayout here.

        }
});

    addTab("Search",0, getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.search_tab ), Venkat.class);
    addTab("Favorite",1, getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.fav_tab ),FavlistScreen.class);
    addTab("List",2, getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.list_tab ),AdslistScreen.class);
    addTab("Filter",3, getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.fav_tab ), FilterScreen.class);
    addTab("Contact Us",4, getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.contact_tab ),  HomeScreen.class);
```

Comment: put some snippet of your code.

Comment: Provide some code for helping you..